# Python | Boto3 - AWS SNS Email formatting issue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I would like to format my output into SNS email body,
but dynamic nature for Elasticbeanstalk is posing a terrible challenge to me.

**CODE:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #Some code to fetch Elasticbeanstalk environement details
    _ _ _ 
    _ _ _ 

    msg = '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'\
    '\n\nHello Team, \n\n Elastic Beanstalk status: \n\n'\
    'Total no.of Elastic beanstalk Environments: '+str(len(envname))+'\n'\
    'EnvironmentName    |  Health   | HealthStatus      | CNAME           \n\n'\
    +str(prin_envname[0])+' | '+str(prin_Ehealth[0])+'       | '+str(prin_Ehealthstatus[0])+'      | '+str(prin_Cname[0])+' \n'\
    +str(prin_envname[1])+' | '+str(prin_Ehealth[1])+'       | '+str(prin_Ehealthstatus[1])+'      | '+str(prin_Cname[1])+' \n'\
    +str(prin_envname[2])+' | '+str(prin_Ehealth[2])+'       | '+str(prin_Ehealthstatus[2])+'      | '+str(prin_Cname[2])+' \n'\
    +str(prin_envname[3])+' | '+str(prin_Ehealth[3])+'       | '+str(prin_Ehealthstatus[3])+'      | '+str(prin_Cname[3])+' \n'\
    '\n'\
    'Total number of EC2 instances associated: '+str(len(envinst))+'\n'\
    '\n'\
    '\n'\
    '\n'\
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'
    send_sns(msg)

def send_sns(msg):
    snsClient = boto3.client('sns',region)
    if msg:
        subject_str = 'Elastic Beanstalkstatus - Environment status' 
        response = snsClient.publish(TopicArn=os.environ['SNS_ARN'],Message=msg,Subject=subject_str)
        print('Publishing Messsage to SNS Topic')
    else:
        print('No content, exiting without sending SNS email..')
```

**CHALLENGE**

Since my Elastic Beanstalk environments in aws account keeps changing from 1 to N,
I cannot predict the number of environments in Elastic Beanstalk.

If you see my print stmts within variable msg for SNS, it is hard coded for 4 environments.

Please suggest on how can I dynamically print the environments in SNS email body.

**CAUTION**

I cannot access 3rd party libraries like Pandas/Numpy etc.,
I can print in sequence as I wish using for loop, but the problem is SNS is accepting only 
msg variable for email body.

Any help/hint/reference are highly and thankfully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours of trial and error, arrived at a working solution for my question.

**Note**: Although am content with my solution, any better solution is always welcome:)

Here's my modified code:

**CODE:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #Some code to fetch Elasticbeanstalk environement details
    _ _ _ 
    _ _ _ 

    # Transposing the list values into rows to columns & columns to rows with below code
    # and creating 2 parameters for designer function
    final_list = []
    pre_final_list = []
    pre_final_list = [envname] + [Ehealth] + [Ehealthstatus] + [Cname]
    final_list = [list(i) for i in zip(*pre_final_list)]

    # Calling designer function with 2 arguments envlen and final_list
    designer_op = designer(envlen,final_list)

    msg = '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'\
    '\n\nHello Team, \n\n Elastic Beanstalk status: \n'\
    'Total no.of Elastic beanstalk Environments: '+str(len(envname))+'\n'\
    'EnvironmentName    |  Health   | HealthStatus      | CNAME           \n'\
    '\n'\
    ''+str(designer_op)+\  # assigning designer function's output
    '\n'\
    'Total number of EC2 instances currently associated: ' +str(len(envinst))+ '\n'\
    '\n'\
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'
    send_sns(msg)

def send_sns(msg):
    snsClient = boto3.client('sns',region)
    if msg:
        subject_str = 'Elastic Beanstalkstatus - Environment status' 
        response = snsClient.publish(TopicArn=os.environ['SNS_ARN'],Message=msg,Subject=subject_str)
        print('Publishing Messsage to SNS Topic')
    else:
        print('No content, exiting without sending SNS email..')

# Designer function to return rows equal to the number of environments
def designer(envlen, final_list):

    if envlen == 10:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[4])+'\n'+str(final_list[5])+'\n'+str(final_list[6])+'\n'+str(final_list[7])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[8])+'\n'+str(final_list[9])+'\n'
        return str(op)

    elif envlen == 9:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[4])+'\n'+str(final_list[5])+'\n'+str(final_list[6])+'\n'+str(final_list[7])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[8])+'\n'
        return str(op)

    elif envlen == 8:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[4])+'\n'+str(final_list[5])+'\n'+str(final_list[6])+'\n'+str(final_list[7])+'\n'
        return str(op)

    elif envlen == 7:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[4])+'\n'+str(final_list[5])+'\n'+str(final_list[6])+'\n'
        return str(op)

    elif envlen == 6:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[4])+'\n'+str(final_list[5])+'\n'
        print('op type ',type(op))
        return str(op)

    elif envlen == 5:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'\
        ''+str(final_list[4])+'\n'
        return op

    elif envlen == 4:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'+str(final_list[3])+'\n'
        return op

    elif envlen == 3:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'+str(final_list[2])+'\n'
        return op

    elif envlen == 2:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'+str(final_list[1])+'\n'
        return op

    elif envlen == 1:
        op = ''+str(final_list[0])+'\n'
        return op
```